# Sharing powerapps application to multiple users

Tags: powerapps

If I develop an application with powerapps :
- How I can send it to many users.
- Does each user consider as a license I have to pay for?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2):

You can share your apps with other users in your organization and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app) is more info on how to do that.

PowerApps is licensed on a per user basis. So you can create as many apps as you want without any special licenses (with the exception of a few extra features) but the person that will use the app needs to have a license. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/pricing-billing-skus) and [also here](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) is more info on our licensing plans. If your org already has Office365 or Dynamics365 you can extend it to add PowerApps. Let me know if the links don't answer your question properly!